# Plugin Development Form Self Submission

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am a new to Wordpress and I am trying to develop a plugin.  All the plugin needs to do is provide an html form for a back end user to fill out then submit.  Once the user hits submit on the form, I want to perform an sql query.

I have the form being created as a tool.  But I cannot get the function to execute when the form is submitted.  I've read the documentation for admin_post_custom_action.  At this point, I am simply trying to get something to dump to the error log so I can see that the function is being called.  My code is below.  The error_log dump works in the initiation portion of the code, so I know my error logging is set up appropriately. Any guidance as to how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (is_admin())
{
    add_action('admin_menu', 'nbn_page_creation_admin_menu');           
    add_action('admin_post_nbn_page_creation_create_page', 'prefix_nbn_page_creation_create_page');
}

function nbn_page_creation_admin_menu() {
    add_submenu_page('tools.php', 'NBN Page Creation', 'NBN Page Creation', 'administrator', 'nbn-page-creation', 'nbn_page_creation_html_page');
}

function prefix_nbn_page_creation_create_page(){
    error_log("Form Submitted!");
}

function nbn_page_creation_html_page() {
    // HTML CODE IS GENERATED SUCCESSFULLY TO THE TOOL PAGE VIA THIS BLOCK THERE IS NO ACTION ON MY FORM ELEMENT BECAUSE WHEN I TRIED TO DO IT ACCORDING TO THE DOCUMENTATION IT SENT ME TO AN EMPTY PHP FILE
}
```

Comment: What does you form action, method, and type look like.

Comment: i have left the action out so that the form posts against itself and the mehtod is post.  for some reason the html code won't post on here... or at least I can't figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out the following:

[Trigger custom action when setting button pressed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/79898/trigger-custom-action-when-setting-button-pressed)

Seems like a similar situation.

Also, have you thought about having the form submit to itself and watching for the `$_REQUEST` variables?